# classnotfound exception reflection

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a Utility class for Java reflection.What my intension is if the method name is passed
as argument, then it should return the value of the Collecton. The utility class is created in Eclipse Plugin  project(`com.abc.utility`).
I added this utility class to another Plugin project(`com.abc.dao`). Now when I call this utility method,I am getting `ClassNotFoundException`.
I understood the problem.I dont want to add the dependency to classes to `com.abc.utility` project. Rather 
`com.abc.utility` plugin project should add as dependency to other projects.

I dont know how to ressolve. Could you please help me out on this.

```java
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public <K>Collection<K> getCollection(T t, String methodName) {

        Method[] methods =t.getClass().getMethods();        

        for (Method method : methods) {         
            String name = method.getName();
            if (name.equals(methodName)) {
                String name2 = method.getReturnType().getName();
                Object newInstance = null;
                try {
                    newInstance = Class.forName(name2).newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (newInstance instanceof Collection) {
                    try {
                        return (Collection)method.invoke(t, null);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Each Eclipse plugin has a separate class path, so in plugin `com.abc.utility` `Class.forName` will only work for classes in the plugin or it dependencies. Other classes will not be in the plugin's class path and it won't be able to find them.

You can load classes in other plugins but only if you know the plugin that contains the class. To do this you use:

```java
Bundle bundle = ... bundle for the plugin containing the class

Class<?> theClass = bundle.loadClass("class name");
```

You can get the `Bundle` from the plugin id using:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```